# trying to multi-thread in python with an infinite loop, however my GUI still freezes

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

So I am pretty inexperienced with programming, but as I am enjoying it, i thought i would branch out and try some stuff. 
The program I am trying to write executes a peice of code i have already written from within a tkinter GUI window and is set to run at a specific time every day until the program is closed. (basically a fancy alarm). to do this i tried to use Threading module to have an infinite 'while' loop run on a different Thread in the background whilst still being able to use the GUI for other things.

```python
def continuous_task(args):
    while 0==0:
        currenttime = time.localtime(time.time())
        if currenttime.tm_hour == 8 and currenttime.tm_min == 0 and currenttime.tm_sec == 0:
            task(args)


def background_task(args):
    thread1 = Thread(target = continuous_task(args))
    thread1.start()
    return None

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.pack()
inputbox = Entry(frame2, width = 20)
inputbox.pack(side = 'left', pady = 10)
header = Label(frame1, text = 'Header', height=3, width = 60)
header.pack(side = 'left')
button = Button(frame2, text = 'Start', width = 10, command = lambda: background_task(inputbox.get()))
button.pack(side = 'left')
Close = Button(frame3, text = 'Close Program', command = root.quit)
Close.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 5)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, the GUI still freezes when i press start, and im a little bit stuck with the debugging of this problem as i don't fully understand the threading module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def background_task(entry_value):
    thread1 = Thread(target=continuous_tasks, args=(entry_value,))
    thread1.start()
    return None
```

Typical miss understood of the `threading` and `multiprocessing` librarys. Writing `target=continous_tasks(args)` is equivalent to running `continuous_tasks(args)` and writing `target=None`

---

As you are new in programming, here are some tips about what you want to try. The function `continuous_tasks` is a function that run at a specific time (hour minute seconds). Checkout the module `schedule`, it is the proper way to do that.

Also, making an infinite loop in a side thread is definitly not a good idea. Avoid doing that, except if you have some interuptions in your thread (like `threading.{Condition,Event,...}`, `time.sleep`), and even if you do, you **definitly should** make a stop condition in your thread.

Comment: Ah right, that fixes my freezing problem so thanks heaps, but coming across another error, when args is entered that way it seems to split each character in 'inputbox' as a seperate argument, when i want the whole thing to be only one argument. 

TypeError: continuous_task() takes 1 positional argument but 13 were given

Comment: Try the following : `def continuous_task(*args):`

Comment: Ho maybe i'm not right. I thought `args` was a tuple, but it's a string. I'm editting

Comment: Oh sweet that made it all work,
I will work on neatening the code up and fixing the while loop problem, thanks for the help